# Do ordinary native speakers understand the phrase "To light a rag under someone"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In the movie *The Sting*, there is a sentence "**You should've seen the rag he lit under Lonnegan!**" as in the following context.

> - Okay, Henry, all clear.
> - Can you believe it? We pulled it off.
> - It's a nice con, Hickey.
> - I thought you were the feds myself when you came in.
> - No trouble, Henry.
> - Snyder went for it all the way.
> - You should've seen the rag he lit under Lonnegan!
> - Well, kid, you beat him.

The phrase "To light a rag under someone" is not in the normal dictionaries, but is explained in [this forum](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/to-light-a-rag-under-someone.3481695/) and in [this blog](https://blindpigandtheacorn.com/appalachian-sayings-light-a-rag/#:%7E:text=light%20a%20rag%20%3D%20to%20leave,also%20called%20light%20a%20shuck) as an Appalachian saying. It does not seem widely used. Would native speakers understand the conversation if they watched the movie?  It is at 7:28 in this [YouTube excerpt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJIZz7VMuA0).

Comment: I'm from the UK, and to me this sounds like a variation of "to light a fire under someone" which is a fairly common expression - and essentially means the same. So, yes. It's quite easy to guess the meaning.

Comment: Billy Kerr, thank you for the comment.  BTW,  who rated the question and what is the reason for the negative score of -1 for the question?  Thank you.

Comment: @user102669 - Downvotes aren't identifiable, and often for no reason good reason. Don't forget to choose one of the answer's given below as best.

Answer (score 3):

I hadn't ever heard *to light a rag under someone*.  However, even out of context, I guessed that it was a variant of [*to light a **fire** under someone*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/light-a-fire-under), which is a common expression meaning "something that forces another person to take action".  Within the context of the movie, this seemed even more clear.  So I think that, although most native speakers would not be familiar with the phrase, they would still understand its general meaning.

Comment: Nate Eldredge, thank you for the comment. For non-native speaker, it is difficult to know the meaning of the idiomatic phrase unless having learned it beforehand.  Sometimes, the idiom has a totally different meaning and can not be easily inferred.  I didn't know the meaning of "light a fire under someone" either.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As a native English-speaker, but one who rarely watches movies and may not be well exposed to that form of language, I must say that I understood "light a rag under" to mean get someone off his/her duff; i.e. cause him/her to not remain inactive (e.g. seated).  I had never before heard that expression, though, so I must admit I had to click the link to your forum reference to verify if my intuition had been correct.

It was mostly correct.  I had imagined the rag being under someone's *seat* rather than under someone's *feet.*  However, the essential meaning was the same.

Comment: I too understood the broad idea, but thought that 'rag' might be more of an emotional incentive, such as in [lose your rag](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lose-rag) and [be like a red rag to a bull](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-like-a-red-rag-to-a-bull?q=red+rag). If I watched the movie, I am sure the meaning in context would be plain.

Comment: Under the seat or under the feet? It's metaphorical – no rag was actually set alight.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, of course I understood it to be metaphorical--but I was thinking more along the lines of "a kick in the seat of the pants" type of metaphor.

Comment: Biblasia, Weather Vane, thank you for the comment.  Since the phrase is an idiomatic expression and is not in the dictionary, I wondered if the majority of the native speaker would understand when they hear it first time in the movie.  "a kick in the seat of the pants", "be like a red rag to a bull", and "lose one's rag" are all new to me. In a fast conversation like in a movie, those expressions are really hard to understand unless you them already. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, I do not believe most native speakers of at least US English would understand the phrase "light a rag." It is argot, jargon of the underworld. But *The Sting* was peppered with argot.

David Maurer, who was a professor of linguistics specializing in slang, jargon, and argot at the time, provides in *The Big Con* the definition of this phrase, and other terms of argot, particularly those pertaining to confidence games, as they were used in 1940, when his book was published.

Quite a few terms pertaining to grift that were used in *The Sting* are defined in this book, and the big-con game of "The Wire" was portrayed in the movie pretty much as it appeared in the book. So was the small-con game of "The Switch" shown at the beginning of the movie.

Some other terms from the movie explained in the book: "Up and Down Broadway," "blew him off/blow off," "braced game," "kayducer," "cold deck," "told him the tale," "boost," "quill," "boodle," "shut-out," and, of course, "sting" (which has since been corrupted in "sucker" (non-grifter) language, making it a "sucker word"). These are the ones I can think of off the top of my head; I'd wager there are more.

The book also covered the ruse in which Gondorff appears to shoot Hooker (the "Cackle-Bladder"), and the use of FBI agent Pogue to help chill the mark ("The Button"). In fact, the book frequently mentions a Charles Gondorff as a prominent inside man. Another name mentioned in the film, this one exactly as it appeared in the book, is "Limehouse Chappie."

The finger-to-nose signal J. J. gives the other members of the gang is one of several called an "office," though this particular gesture has a different meaning when described in the book. We also see that saloon-keeper Duke Boudreau is a local "fixer," and may surmise that Kid Twist has that moniker because he is a lady's man.

If you were to read the book and then watch the movie, I think you would be amazed at how many of the phrases, scenarios, and actions are described in Maurer's book.

In summary, *The Sting* contains many phrases that are specific to grift and cons and are not understood by most native speakers; "light a rag" is only one of several.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While interesting information, this doesn't answer whether the phrase is widely understood.

Comment: Thank you Dr. Vigg for providing detailed additional info.  The cons and grift must have been rampant at that time in the American society.  It is no wonder that I have a hard time following and understanding the movie.  Thank you.